# Hibernate doesn't make changes in PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a strange problem with Hibernate. I can select something from database, but I can't insert or update any value. Here is my configuration and example code, persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="UserDS">

        <class>****User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myuser"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mypasword"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "abc", schema = "public")
public class Abc {

    @Id
    private String aa;

    private Integer bb;

    public String getAa() {
        return aa;
    }

    public void setAa(String aa) {
        this.aa = aa;
    }

    public Integer getBb() {
        return bb;
    }

    public void setBb(Integer bb) {
        this.bb = bb;
    }
}
```

and DAO:

```
public class TestDOA{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="UserDS")
    private EntityManager em;

    public String test() {          
        abc ab = (abc) em.createQuery("FROM abc").getResultList().get(0);
        ab.setBb(123);
        em.persist(ab);
        em.flush();
        return ab.getAa() + " " + ab.getBb();
    }
```

When I use test method, I get properly values. In server's log file I can see

`[stdout] (default task-7) Hibernate: update public.abc set bb=? where aa=?`

but there is no changes in my database. Where is the problem ?

Comment: You forgot you @transactional

Comment: The problem is most probably that you don't have any transaction being committed.

Comment: Ok, I added @Transactional additionality above test() method but It still doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: I've just noticed that after calling em.persist() transaction is not blocked (I can't call update statement in pgadmin). I have to restart WildFly server to unlock transaction. I have no idea...

Comment: @Hannes Only if they're using Spring Framework, right?

Comment: @CraigRinger Correct. A more generic question would have been: is a transaction in place and does it get comitted afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the transaction isn't getting committed at any point. You can confirm this by examining `pg_stat_activity` on the database server - you'll see one or more `<IDLE> in transaction` entries for connections from your app server.

You need to decide if you're using JTA transactions or explicit transaction management.

If you're using Java EE 6 + JTA, you [need to add appropriate annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html). Remember that JTA is only supported for EJBs and (in some app servers) CDI beans; a `@TransactionManagement` annotation silently has no effect on other objects.

If you're using Spring + JTA, you'll need to [look up the docs for the `@Transactional` annotation and the rules around it instead](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

If you're going to use explicit transaction management directly with the persistence provier you must begin and commit the transaction (the begin is implicit but it's better to write it explicitly) using `em.getTransaction().begin();` and `em.getTransaction().commit();`